# How to capture "send mail" in plugin for IBM Lotus notes

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Here is what I am trying to do:
Add a special button to attach files to Notes "New message" window. If files were attached using this button, when email sent, they should be uploaded to the server and link to them added to the email.

My question - is it possible (and how) to capture "send mail" event in the plugin for Lotus Notus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of figured it out. There is a very nice extension point provided in 8.5 - "com.ibm.notes.mailsend.MailSendAttachmentsDialog", that is specifically exists for custom handling of attachments. You can see it in plugin.xml, in IBM\Lotus\Notes\framework\shared\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.notes.mailsend_8.5.***.jar.

The only problem is - it handles just attachments and does not have access to anything else. So if somebody figured how to get subject line and the message text from there, please reply.

Update: got it.

```
NotesUIElement elem = (new NotesUIWorkspace()).getCurrentElement();
if (elem instanceof NotesUIDocument) {
NotesUIDocument doc = ((NotesUIDocument) elem);
String to = doc.getField("EnterSendTo").getText();
String cc = doc.getField("EnterCopyTo").getText();
String bcc = doc.getField("EnterBlindCopyTo").getText();
String subject = doc.getField("Subject").getText();
String body = doc.getField("Body").getText();
    ....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how an Eclipse plugin would do this.  Furthermore, since Notes can be used off-line -- when it would be impossible to upload files to a server -- it would be better to have code running on the Domino server intercept the mail messages and perform the upload.

Most products that hook mail operations on the server use the Lotus Notes C API's Extension Manager functions to hook the EM_BEFORE notification for the EM_NSFNOTEUPDATE event and check whether the NSFNoteUpdate operation occurred within the server's mail.box files, and then check whether the the message requires special processing (i.e., in your case that would be by looking for a special NotesItem that your button code has inserted into the message). The usual coding method for this is to immediately change the status of the message to put it on hold, preventing the Domino router from attempting to send the message while your code is still working on it.  Many products actually have two components - the EM hook DLL and a separate server task that receives a signal from the hook DLL, processes the message, and then releases it from on hold status.  This approach keeps your code from tying up router threads while processing large files.

(Note: Newer versions of the Domino server have the ability to use OSGI plugins written in Java instead of using the Notes C API for operations like this.  I've not looked into the details of how this might work for operations that process mail messages.  )